# How to remove relative shift in matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

When I try to do a plot against a range with big enough numbers I get an axis with relative shift for all the ticks. For example:

```
plot([1000, 1001, 1002], [1, 2, 3])
```

I get these ticks on axis of abscissas:

```
0.0     0.5     1.0     1.5     2.0
                               +1e3
```

The question is how to remove `+1e3` and get just:

```
1000.0  1000.5  1001.0  1001.5  1002.0
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
plot([1000, 1001, 1002], [1, 2, 3])
gca().get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
draw()
```

This grabs the current `axes`, gets the x-axis `axis` object and then the major formatter object and sets useOffset to false ([doc](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter)).

In newer versions (1.4+) of matplotlib the default behavior can be changed via the `axes.formatter.useoffset` rcparam.

Answer (score 3):

To disable relative shift everywhere, set the rc parameter:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('axes.formatter', useoffset=False)
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some explanation to your answer so it is not just code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Updated to add an explanation.