# Change the text of the offset in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to change the text of the offset in matplotlib. I made a plot:

```
x = linspace(0, 11, 1000)
plot(x,2000*(1-exp(-x))+randn(1000))
axis((10.3, 11, 1996.9, 2002.9))
```

[image]

Than the offset is written in the form +1.996e+3. It seems to me too difficult. I want to change it to +1996, or disable to use offset at all.
I tried it as follows:

```
t = gca().yaxis.get_offset_text()
t.set_text('+1996')
```

It have not worked. What is the right way? Or can I set the format of the offset? Or how can I disable to use offsets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442099/matplotlib-how-to-show-all-digits-on-ticks/14443979#14443979 -> how to turn the offset off

Comment: `set_scientific` seems like it should do what you want, but it does not.  This smells like a bug to me.  I will dig into this more later if I have time.

Comment: I like the other answer for that question as well. Thank you!

Comment: beware of using `FixedFormatter`, it means that the mouse-over value (in the lower left) will no longer update.

Comment: The question below has a lot of similarity with the current one, and sf.set_scientific does not worked for me in the way the answer (of Saullo Castro) said.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962958/scientific-tick-label-notation-tuning