# Scientific tick label notation tuning

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am not completely satisfied with the default scientific formatting for the tick labels. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

pylab.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
pylab.ticklabel_format(style='sci')

pylab.figure(1)
pylab.clf()
pylab.scatter(range(10),np.linspace(-21.305,-21.300,10))
pylab.show()
```

gives a picture with ticklabels of the form

[image]

What's wrong in here is firstly that `-2.1298x10^1` should be in my opinion `-21.298`, and in general I would only like to see only exponents divisible with 3 (`10^3`, `10^6` etc and in the case of `10^0` i would like to hide it as in `-21.298`).

Also, I would like to have instead of `0.000` and `-0.002` and so on `0` and `-2` so that the exponent `10^-3` is included to the `-21.298` so that in total the ticklabels would be

```
   x 10^-3 - 21.298
 0
-2
-4
-6
```

Now, have I missed some easy way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the [`ScalarFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

sf = ScalarFormatter()
sf.set_scientific(True)
sf.set_powerlimits((-0.00001, 0.00001))

ax = pylab.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(sf)
pylab.show()
```

You can test what the formatter will do to a given number by passing the number to `format_data()`:

```
sf.format_data(0.002)
#'2{\\times}10^{-3}'
```

Comment: I have run the first four row of your code in ipython shell with --pylab option, then sr.format_data(0.02). It wrote '2e-3'. (Python 3.4.3, IPython 1.2.1, pylab version 1.10.0.post2)

Answer (score 1):

```py
ax.ticklabel_format(style='scientific', scilimits=(-1, 2), axis='y',useMathText=True)
```

set `useMathText=True` to turn 1e-3 to 10 \ times -3