# matplotlib screws up float axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axes

I've a problem with my Matplotlib graph.

My Programm:
I read sensor data and save it in a csv file with one decimal place (00.0)
after saving I readout the individual data into a list
my list is called tempList and the numbers are float

My Plot:

```
plt.plot(tempList, color='r', linewidth=2.0)     
plt.xticks(range(len(tempList)), timeList2, size='small', rotation=20) 
plt.axis('auto')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('degree Celsius')
plt.title('Temperature')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('img/temp.png', format='png', transparent = True)
plt.close()
```

My result:
http://s24.postimg.org/5ewu74w51/temp.png

My List:
[20.3, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4]

if I make a list with int's everything works, but since I need thoose decimal places I can't use int.
I already tried to set 'ylim' but it doesn't work

EDIT:
thanks for the help
I removed the 'plt.axis('auto')'
the solution:

```
minTemp = math.ceil(min(tempList))
minTemp = round(minTemp, 1)
maxTemp = math.ceil(max(tempList))
maxTemp = round(maxTemp, 1)
plt.ylim((minTemp-1), (maxTemp+1))

plt.ylim((minTemp-1), (maxTemp+1))
```

Comment: You need to give access to the location where you post the file if you want any help...

Comment: The title suggests that there seems to be some kind of bug, however, if the way matplotlib labels your axis is the problem, then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14442099/2870069 -> no bug, just "default" behavior.

Comment: thanks for the link, that solved another issue I had :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this minimal example.
I removed plt.axis('auto') and replaced it with plt.ylim, which seems to work.
When I replace plt.ylim by plt.axis('auto'), it doesn't work very well.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
tempList = [20.3, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4]
plt.plot(tempList)
plt.ylim(math.floor(min(tempList)), math.ceil(max(tempList)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: works fine, but I don't want to have 0 as start point.    So now I tried the min instead of 0 and everything looks like before.

Comment: What if you use: plt.ylim(math.floor(min(tempList)), math.ceil(max(tempList)))