# How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm using Matplotlib in Python to plot simple x-y datasets. This produces nice-looking graphs, although when I "zoom in" too close on various sections of the plotted graph using the Figure View (which appears when you execute `plt.show()` ), the x-axis values change from standard number form (1050, 1060, 1070 etc.) to scientific form with exponential notation (e.g. 1, 1.5, 2.0 with the x-axis label given as `+1.057e3`).

I'd prefer my figures to retain the simple numbering of the axis, rather than using exponential form. Is there a way I can force Matplotlib to do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063

Comment: Obsolete answers. For an updated version, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371674/8881141

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The formatting of tick labels is controlled by a `Formatter` object, which assuming you haven't done anything fancy will be a `ScalerFormatter`[by default](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter).  This formatter will use a constant shift if the fractional change of the values visible is very small.  To avoid this, simply turn it off:

```
plt.plot(arange(0,100,10) + 1000, arange(0,100,10))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.draw()
```

If you want to avoid scientific notation in general,

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

Can control this with globally via the `axes.formatter.useoffset` rcparam.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Apologies for the duplicate question too - I did search before posting it, but my searches included terms such as "scientific notation" and "exponential form" rather than "relative axis shifts", which is what the previous user used.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently force this change? I've never found the scientific notation axes and always end up turning them off. I couldn't see an rcParam for this though.

Comment: @IanRoberts See update it is the `axes.formatter.useoffset` rcparam

Comment: Great, thanks! I'd personally prefer to see this set to False by default, since it seems to confuse many and benefit few.

Comment: True, good point. That was a fairly unsubstantiated claim, although I have seen quite a few people asking how to disable this. Anyway, this fix solves it nicely so I can forget about this for now... Cheers

Comment: I can't get this to work; see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336020/prevent-axes-from-being-in-scientific-notation-powers-of-10-using-matplotlib-i

Answer (score 37):

You can use a simpler command to turn it off:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Comment: You might need to specify the axis with `axis='x'` for instance, in case you get an `AttributeError` about `ScalarFormatters`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use something like:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me whilst using a log axis. Other options I tried all raised attribute errors, e.g. `AttributeError: 'LogFormatterSciNotation' object has no attribute 'set_scientific'`

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command:
`ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`

If you are using a subplot, you may experience the `AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter` in which case you would add `axis='y'` like the below. You can change 'y' to the axis with the issues.

```
ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain', axis='y')
```

Source question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot). Note, the `axis 'y'` command use is hidden in the answer comments.

Answer (score 5):

I have used below code before the graphs, and it worked seamless for me..

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I didn't want scientific numbers to be shown when I zoom in, and the following worked in my case too. I am using Lat/Lon in labeling where scientific form doesn't make sense.

```py
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```