# Matplotlib transforms values when graphing

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I graph floats with a bunch of decimal digits, Matplotlib keeps trying to be clever and plots only the least significant digits, while adding the most significant digits in the corner (for both axes). How do I stop this behaviour!?[image]

I want it to plot 5.4315, 5.4316 etc...

Comment: being pedantic, it is _plotting_ all of your data correctly and exactly as you passed it in, it is just adding (subtracting) an offset to the tick labels.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi/14711866#14711866

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to mark as duplicate. But this is answered.

Comment: Either just leave it (it has 2/5 close votes needed to be marked as a duplicate) or use the flag link, select other and explain that this is a duplicate.