# Prevent matplotlib from "adding" to axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I stop Matplotlib from adding this value in the corner in the figure attached? The figure is generated from two lists of data by the source code:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)
ax1.scatter(x, y1, marker=',',s=1, c='k')
ax1.axis([0., x, y1min, y1max])
ax2.scatter(x, y2, marker=',',s=1, c='k')
ax2.axis([0., x, y2min, y2max])
```

[image: addition plot]

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: [this is a similar question...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3677368/832621) it may help you out

Comment: [This answer is what you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14711866/406772)

Comment: @webb Where in the matplotlib documentation would you have tried to look to find this?  This is a persistent enough issue that I want to add some to the docs, but am having trouble trying to figure out _where_ to put it.

Comment: @tcaswell I wasn't even sure where to look at all. I searched things like "addition on axis" things like that. Really, it should by default be off and an opt-in thing. I never see plots with the axis offset printed above the axis in publications.

Comment: This particular case looks like it should not have been triggered (as it did not actually save any space.  This is some-what standard in (at least) physics journals.  Please see 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3168

Comment: Yeah, agreeing about the default behavior. It should probably have a new name and be default turned off...