# No exponential form of the z-axis in matplotlib-3D-plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have a similar problem as described in [How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi):

I don't want that (in my special case) weird scientific formatting of the axis. My problem is different as I have this problem at my `z`-Axis. For 2-D plots I can use `ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`. And there is no function `ax.get_zaxis()`

What do I use to format my `z`-Axis the same way?

EDIT: Example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def func(xi, ti):
    res = 10e3 + np.cos(ti) * np.sin(xi)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timeSpacing = 20
    timeStart = 0
    timeEnd = 1
    time = np.linspace(timeStart, timeEnd, timeSpacing)
    widthSpacing = 50
    widthStart = 0
    widthEnd = 3
    width = np.linspace(widthStart, widthEnd, widthSpacing)
    resList = []
    matplotlib.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
    for i, item in enumerate(time):
        ti = [item for t in width]
        res = func(width, ti)
        ax.plot(width, ti, res, 'b')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('t')
    ax.set_zlabel('f(x,t)')
    pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Obvious work-around would be to adjust the z-values of your data accordingly.

Comment: And then? Then there is still an axis than i can't configure properly. And further more, in general i like to pot f(x,y) over x and y, and not in some weird way that confuses the viewer.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I edited an example to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, there is no `get_zaxis()` method. But, fortunately, there is `zaxis` field (so don't add `()`). There are also `xaxis` and `yaxis` fields, so you can use all of those uniformly instead of `get_...axis()` if you like.

For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
    ax.zaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False) # here
    for i, item in enumerate(time):
        ...
```

and the end result should look something like this:

[image: new plot that doesn't use exponential form]

As you can see, for large numbers it might not look so well...