# How to repress scientific notation in factorplot y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Simple example below for this issue which I just can't solve.

N.B. Some other Seaborn plotting methods seems to have arguments to repress the exponential form but seemingly not `factorplots`. I tried some Matplotlib solutions including those suggested in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi) but none work. Also this is not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804658/prevent-scientific-notation-in-seaborn-boxplot). I use factorplots very frequently and ideally want to find a proper solution as opposed to a workaround.

```
data = {'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],'coverage': [35050800, 54899767, 57890789, 62890798, 70897871]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Produces this dataframe:

```
    coverage    reports
0   35050800    4
1   54899767    24
2   57890789    31
3   62890798    2
4   70897871    3
```

And then this Seaborn code:

```
sns.factorplot(y="coverage", x="reports", kind='bar', data=df, label="Total")
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Is there a way to get the y axis to display an appropriate numeric scale based on the `coverage` values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this possibility GWW - I had seen that question and tried the solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Have You tried `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')`?

Comment: @TonyBabarino - Never thought of that. Works perfectly. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: posted, glad I could help, cheers!

Comment: @RDJ: I retracted my vote.  I used the duplicate answer before with success so I am surprised it didn't work for you.

Comment: @gww I would be interested to know exactly how you did it syntactically as it definitely didn't work the way I tried it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like the following line solves the issue:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

Here is the [documentation link](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format).

Answer (score 6):

Following line solved the issue for me (addition to Tony's answer)

`sns.plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y',useOffset=False)`

Comment: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'

Answer (score 0):

You can use globally the "rc-Paramter" when you don't want to import and deal with matplotlib directly.

```
sns.set_theme(rc={'axes.formatter.limits': (-8, 9)})
```

See:

- https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_theme.html
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html