# Remove scientific notation from catplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

Executing the following:

```
g = sns.catplot(
    x="price",
    y="neigh",
    kind="bar",
    data=top_bot)
g = g.set(title = "Mean of the top and bottom prices (euros) by neighbour")
```

[image]

The `x` ticks are being converted to scientific notation. I would like to specify the ticks to use, and also remove the scientific notation from them. I tried several approaches already posted in ´SO´, but the problem is that neither of them worked specifically with `catplot`.

Edit:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780948/seaborn-matplotlib-how-to-repress-scientific-notation-in-factorplot-y-axis) solution doesn't solve my problem at all. For `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')` creates an empty plot, followed by the same plot in scientific notation. and for `sns.plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y',useOffset=False)` it outputs
`AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'`

Comment: can you provide an example of your data? and also the code you tried

Comment: @mosc9575 this outputs the following error: `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'ticklabel_format'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use seaborn and matplotlib functionality together.
You have to create a matplotlib figure first and make all the changes you need. Than call the seaborn function and adding the information about the axes you want to use.

This is a working minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# data
top_bot = pd.DataFrame({'price':[i*100000000 for i in range(5)], 'neigh': range(10,15)})
# creating figure
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='both')
sns.barplot(x='price', y='neigh', data=top_bot, ax=ax)
```

This example ia different from your picture, because you did not share the data you have plotted and the code you tried.

I hope this answers your question.