# Changing Range in Y axis of Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

How can I change the y-axis values to show the full number of digits?

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot (x="waterfront", y="price", data=df)
```

I wanted the full range of digits to show (as in screenshot "target"), but the boxplot I created shows an annotated one (as in screenshot "current").

Target:

[image: Target scale]

Current:

[image: Current scale]

Comment: Please show the code that you have done the figures with. In addition, your question does not state what python library you are using for creating the box plot. :)

Comment: import seaborn as sns     
sns.boxplot (x="waterfront", y="price", data=df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer from here: [Seaborn / Matplotlib: How to repress scientific notation in factorplot y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780948/seaborn-matplotlib-how-to-repress-scientific-notation-in-factorplot-y-axis)

This is the code you need:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.boxplot (x="waterfront", y="price", data=df)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y',useOffset=False)
```

[image: example picture]

Answer (score 0):

This code you need copy:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


custom_palette = ['#2477BF', '#F26101']

# Define flier properties to change marker style and color
flierprops = dict(marker='D', markerfacecolor=['grey', '#2477BF'], markersize=4, linestyle='none')

sns.boxplot(x='waterfront', y='price', data=df, palette=custom_palette, flierprops=flierprops)

# Set y-axis format to avoid scientific notation
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y', useOffset=True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).