# Plotting a curve from numpy array with large values

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a curve from molecular dynamics potential energies data stored in numpy array. As you can see from my figure attached, on the top left of the figure, a large number appears which is related to the label on y-axis. Look at it.
[image] 
Even if I rescale the data, still a number appears there. I do not want it. Please can you suggest me howto sort out this issue? Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

This is likely happening because your data is a small value offset by a large one.  That's what the `-` sign means at the front of the number, "take the plotted y-values and subtract this number to get the actual values".  You can remove it by plotting with the mean subtracted.  Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = -1.5*1e7 + np.random.random(100)

plt.plot(y)
plt.ylabel("units")
```

gives the form you don't like:
[image]

but subtracting the mean (or some other number close to that, like `min` or `max`, etc) will remove the large offset:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y - np.mean(y))
plt.ylabel("offset units")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the offset by using:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems your data is displayed in exponential form like: 1e+10, 2e+10, etc.
This question here might help:

[How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comments