# pyplot display large numbers in interactive mode

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, interactive-mode

I'm trying to plot large numbers on the x axis using the interactive mode, and instead of the full number on the ticks, i get 1, 1.5 and so on and +5.043e3. how can i display the full number?

After defining the `plt.ion()`, i have this inside a loop:

```
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (angstroms)")
plt.ylabel("Arbitrary Flux")
plt.plot(xo,yo,'k--')
    for e in range(multispec):
    if ( e == 0):
        plt.plot(MX[e],MY[e], 'r-')
    else:
    plt.plot(MX[e],MY[e])
l=float(int(n))
plt.axis([n-1, n+1, 0.1, 1.1])
```

n is other variable defined in a for.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[copied from [How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi) ]

The formatting of tick labels is controlled by a `Formatter` object, which assuming you haven't done anything fancy will be a `ScalerFormatter`[by default][1].  This formatter will use a constant shift if the fractional change of the values visible is very small.  To avoid this, simply turn it off:

```
plt.plot(arange(0,100,10) + 1000, arange(0,100,10))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.draw()
```

If you want to avoid scientific notation in general,

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

Comment: it didn't work, but in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi  the other procedure worked as well. thanks!

Comment: sorry, miss-read your question.