# How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib 1.4.3 figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using Matplotlib in Python to plot simple x-y datasets. This produces really nice-looking graphs, although when I "zoom in" too close on various sections of the plotted graph using the Figure View (which appears when you execute plt.show(), the x-axis values change from standard number form (1050, 1060, 1070 etc.) to scientific form with exponentials (e.g. 1, 1.5, 2.0 with the x-axis label given as +1.057e3).

I'd prefer my figures to retain the simple numbering of the axis, rather than using exponential form. Is there a way I can force Matplotlib to do this please?

the answers in the link dos not work in matplotlib 1.4.3

[How to remove relative shift in matplotlib axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063)

Thanks

Comment: The answer mentions how to use them for matplotlib versions 1.4 and higher.

Comment: The method described in the comment did not work