# convert scientific notation to real number on ggplot python

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, axis, scientific-notation

I'm tryin to make a plot with pythons ggplot but the x and y aaxes are showing up in scientific notation

this is my code:

```
ggplot(dfMerge, aes(x='rent_price',y='sale_price', color='outlier',label='name')) +\
geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0, size=20) +\
geom_point() +\
scale_y_continuous(labels="%.2f") +\
xlab("Rent Unit Price") +\
ylab("Sale Unit Price") +\
stat_smooth(color='blue')
```

Here's the plot i get:
[image]

How can i change the exponetial values on the axes to real numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually a matplotlib question. You want to set the `useoffset` attribute of the axes formatters to `False` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063

Comment: Tried it but it doesnt change anything.I'm lost ass per what to do about it. Thanks anyway

Comment: you should update to question to show us what you've tried.