# non-scientific format for labels on axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to set non-scientific format for labels on axes?
I tried:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x', scilimits=(0, 0), useLocale='True')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0), useLocale='True')
```

However, I get result as in the picture. 
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)

Comment: ... which is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063) :D

Comment: I read this question, but I don't know what to do with `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined
> <string>(1)<module>()->None` when I use for instance: `ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)`